# Excessive CPU usage on Golang stdin loop

Tags: go

I have a golang app which needs to listen for input on stdin - not as a command line utility but to keep running and listening.  The following code, slightly edited down, works but has very high CPU load when 'idle' - and I am not sure why - nor clear how this could be done better.  So I need the same functionality without the CPU load! (this is part of an authentication handler for ejabberd)

```
bioIn := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
bioOut := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)

var err error
var success bool
var length uint16
var result uint16

for {
    binary.Read(bioIn, binary.BigEndian, &length)

    buf := make([]byte, length)

    r, _ := bioIn.Read(buf)
    if r == 0 {
        continue
    }

    if err == nil {
        data := strings.Split(string(buf), ":")
        // I have code to handle the incoming data here...
    } else {
        success = false
    }

    length = 2
    binary.Write(bioOut, binary.BigEndian, &length)

    if success != true {
        result = 0
    } else {
        result = 1
    }

    binary.Write(bioOut, binary.BigEndian, &result)
    bioOut.Flush()
}
```

**ANSWER:**

I added a short sleep as suggested and this has worked a charm; didn't need to be long and no noticeable impact on the authentication the service is providing. With the reassurance incoming data is buffered this is perfect fix. Thanks all.

```
r, _ := bioIn.Read(buf)
    if r == 0 {
        time.Sleep(25 * time.Millisecond)
        continue
}
```

Comment: Do not use buf past index r. string(buf) is garbage, string(buf[:r]) is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tight infinite loop, which will always take as much CPU as the OS will allow. You are always checking to see if there's any input and (in your sample code) you never wait for new input - you just continuously poll stdin to see if there is any. You should probably use `time.Sleep()` to wait some time between each check.

Comment: Thanks Zarenor - if I have a short sleep will it 'always' get the stdin data when it next goes around the loop.. that is, I won't lose data if it is asleep when something comes in - will it??

Comment: Unless you have something else consuming from stdin, I don't see how it would. It should be left in stdin until you consume it.

Comment: I have added a sleep and this has completely solved the cpu load.. didn't need to be long - see edit.

Answer (score 2):

In this part of your code:

```
 r, _ := bioIn.Read(buf)
 if r == 0 {
      continue
  }
```

You check for a return value of 0, which means EOF. i.e. the input stream has ended/terminated. Once `stdin` is terminated, it's not going to come back. So you have an endless loop here. it'll just spin around on this test having `bioIn.Read()` return 0 every time.

You can't really do much more than quit/exit at that point, stdin doesn't have any more data for you, ever.

Note that your code also discard the error returned from `bioIn.Read()` - don't do that, deal with errors - and you would have discovered the cause for yourself in this case.

Comment: Checking the returned error instead of discarding it would also avoid this issue.

Comment: Your point is right, but depending on what stdin is connected to, it's actually possible that it *does* have more data after EOF. A terminal can send EOF but then have more input, and a file can be appended to, if you wait. Generally the thing you want to do is to read any given stream until EOF and then terminate, but not *absolutely* always :)

Comment: It is by design / needed that this is an infinite loop - because further 'signals' will arrive via stdin later.  My problem is that his is soaking too many resources.   If I put a sleep in that 'if r==0 ' block, will it always pickup stdin data next time round the loop - ie. it will not 'lose' data just because it is having a few ms rest?

Comment: No, no data loss. The data is being buffered until your next read from it.

Comment: @hobbs, as far as I know io.EOF means the reader has closed gracefully; no future read will succeed. There is no byte that means EOF.

Comment: @Peter EOF is a flag, not a byte, but it's a flag that can be cleared. As an example, run `perl -` at a Unix terminal, then enter `print while <>;`, Enter, ^D, Enter, `Hello`, Enter, ^D. It will print `Hello` to the screen. perl reads stdin to EOF to get its code, and then the code reads stdin to EOF *again*.

Comment: @Peter another classic example would be `tail -f`.